# Behavior of ActiveMQ with N producers and 1 consumer

Tags: activemq-classic, producer-consumer, stress-testing

In my architecture I have many producers who want to send messages to an ActiveMQ queue. A consumer will consume these messages from that queue in real time. Though the production of these messages is very fast the queue seems to be able to handle them. No messages are lost.

My purpose here is to stress this architecture, but I cannot find a documentation that explain what kind of problems might happen in this scenario. For example, could message loss happen? If so, when? Can the reception of messages produced by a producer P1 be inhibited by a huge production of messages from another producer P2?

I'm sending persistent JMS messages using this Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
   <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
   <version>5.15.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's my producer code:

```java
// producer

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;


//Producer constructor
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = session.createQueue(jmsQueue); 
producer = session.createProducer(destination);
...

//OnMessage do this
        try {
            stream(message);
        } catch(JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e);
        }


private void stream(LogRecord message) throws JMSException {        
    TextMessage toSend =session.createTextMessage(message.getMessage());
    producer.send(toSend);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think I'm sending persistent messages, given that  the delivery mode is set to PERSISTENT by default. I created my client using the library javax.jms.

Comment: I added the code of the producer, to make my question more complete

Comment: You are referring to the dependecy that I imported in the pom about ActiveMQ ?? Otherwise I don't know what it is a client library D:

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.15</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Based on the code you pasted it appears you may be creating a connection, session, and producer for *every* message you send. This is a well-known anti-pattern that will hurt performance significantly and should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: I don't reported all the code of the application because was not related to the question, so I wrote only the pieces about ActiveMQ. In a constructor of an Object who is working as a logger for a producer,  I'm creating the session, than every time that I have to log a message, I call the stream method of the LoggerObject.  So given that the constructor is called only at the begin, I should have only one session per producer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending persistent messages then no message loss should happen short of a disk failure of some kind on the broker.

The essential speed of the broker can be maintained **if and only if** consumption keeps pace with production. Once messages start accumulating on the broker then either the messages fill up the heap and increase pressure on garbage collection or the messages will have to be paged out of memory to disk. In either case, performance will suffer. Keep in mind that ActiveMQ brokers are designed to be a conduit *through which* messages flow. They are not a storage platform like a database. They can buffer messages for a time, but if messages keep accumulating eventually a tipping point will come when performance degrades.

For what it's worth, if you're looking for the best performance from an ActiveMQ broker I would recommend taking a look at [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) - the next generation broker from ActiveMQ.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Using persistent messages, if a prodocer P1 sent these messages {m1,m2,m3} is guaranteed that activeMQ will stored them to be consumed in the queue in the same order ??

Comment: Is P1 a JMS producer? If so, is it sending m1, m2, & m3 using the same `javax.jms.Session` instance?

Comment: Yes it is. And yes I created a Session istance once at the begin, for every producer

Comment: Since m1, m2, & m3 are sent in that order using the same `javax.jms.Session` instance then they will put on the queue in that same order. This is guaranteed by the JMS specification.